# document.get / Inner HTML Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some issues figuring out how to make the innerHTML/GetElement line of code to work. I have tried all other commands such as `document.write` and `alert`, both seem to work fine. I don't know how to structure the `document.get` to include the `getRandomArrayElements` function. I am rather new to the Javascript side of web development and have been playing around with code on here. Im trying to have a array always give me 3 numbers of the list when pressing the button. Everything is working except the alert and my attempt to get it responded to the button press. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" onclick="getRandomArrayElements();" />
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function getRandomArrayElements(arr, count) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
    while (i-- > min) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled.slice(min);
}
```

> Here is where im having issues, I just want the function to rely on the button press and not on the alert and no matter how many variations I do of removing alert and combining the code of the last two lines it comes out wrong.

```
var numbers = ['1','2','4','5','5','7','8','9','10'];
alert( getRandomArrayElements(numbers, 3) );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=random;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to set to innerHTML is not set. Try this snippet:

```js
function getRandomArrayElements(count) {

var arr = ['1','2','4','5','5','7','8','9','10'];
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
    while (i-- > min) {
        index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=shuffled.slice(min);
}
```

```html
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" onclick="getRandomArrayElements(3);" />
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that snippet to the top of my code, I have that in my version i forgot to paste it here, ill will fix that. But the snippet you provided is exactly what i had. I will try the var random now.